# In GCP- how do I get a list of all prices

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would like to get all the different prices for different services in GCP in a REST API call.

Do I have to use the API of each service to get this, or is there one call that could get all the info on the different GCP services ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation [Get Started with the Cloud Billing API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/getting-started):

> For the [Cloud Billing Catalog API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api):
>
> - Programmatic access to the entire public Google Cloud catalog consisting of:
>
>   - Billable SKUs
>   - **Public pricing**
>   - Relevant metadata
> - You can access the Cloud Billing API in one of the following ways:
>
>   - **REST API**.
>   - RPC API.

more details you can found at the section [Get Google Cloud pricing information](https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api):

> This page shows you how to use the Cloud Billing Catalog API to:
>
> - **Get a list of all public services** including relevant metadata about each service.
> - **Get a list of all public SKUs** within a service including:
> - Human readable description of the SKU.
> - Public pricing of the SKU.
> - Regions where the SKU is available for purchase.
> - Categorization data about the SKU.

with examples how to do it.

Keep in mind that calling the Cloud Billing Catalog API requires an [API Key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys).

You can use the Cloud Billing Catalog API with your existing cost management tools, as well as to reconcile list pricing rates when you export billing data to Google BigQuery.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for :-)